# MYSQL Daily Data Compare Last Week vs Two Weeks Ago

Tags: mysql

I have daily data for multiple locations that we need to compare last week total sales with total sales 2 weeks ago.  Here is the MYSQL code

```
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(date) = WEEK(now())-1 THEN sales ELSE NULL END) as 'Last Week',
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(date) = WEEK(now())-2 THEN sales ELSE NULL END) as '2 Weeks Ago',
    SUM('1week' - '2week') AS 'Change'
FROM daily_sales
GROUP BY name
```

The output for the 1st three columns is correct, but I cannot get the 4th column "change" to calculate correctly.  Tried SUM of the cases but could not get over invalid use og group function:

```
SUM((SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(date) = WEEK(now())-1 THEN sales ELSE NULL END)) 
- (SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(date) = WEEK(now())-2 THEN sales ELSE NULL END))) AS 'change'
```

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there; just take the formula that give cols 2 and 3 and put a minus between them:

```
SELECT 
  name, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(date) = WEEK(now())-1 THEN sales END) as LastWeek, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(date) = WEEK(now())-2 THEN sales END) as TwoWeeksAgo,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(date) = WEEK(now())-1 THEN sales END) - SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(date) = WEEK(now())-2 THEN sales END) as change
FROM daily_sales
WHERE date >= date_sub(now(), interval 3 week)
GROUP BY name
```

Or by use of a subquery:

```
SELECT name, lastweek, twoweeksago, lastweek - twoweeksago as change
FROM
(
 SELECT 
  name, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(date) = WEEK(now())-1 THEN sales END) as LastWeek, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(date) = WEEK(now())-2 THEN sales END) as TwoWeeksAgo
 FROM daily_sales
 WHERE date >= date_sub(now(), interval 3 week)
 GROUP BY name
) x
```

Or by use of a cte:

```
WITH x AS(
 SELECT 
  name, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(date) = WEEK(now())-1 THEN sales END) as LastWeek, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(date) = WEEK(now())-2 THEN sales END) as TwoWeeksAgo
 FROM daily_sales
 WHERE date >= date_sub(now(), interval 3 week)
 GROUP BY name
)

SELECT name, lastweek, twoweeksago, lastweek - twoweeksago as change
```

Comment: Thanks!  I tried that sooo many times...probably an errant "("

Comment: Another way to do these things is to use a subquery to reduce repetition, I'll add an example